# c++ reading line by line but not able to show output line by line

Tags: c++

I am trying to run a C++ code. My input file has number of lines and I am trying remove the spaces in each line and then display. But, when i run the code the output is coming in a single line i.e all thelines of the file are being shown in one single line.

Please solve my problem , so that i get the output line by line.

Thanks.

I have tried this code. This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0, len, j;
    std::string str;
    ifstream iFile("g.txt");
    while (std::getline(iFile, str) != 0)
    {
        len = str.length();
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] == ' ')
            {
                for (j = i; j < len; j++)
                {
                    str[j] = str[j + 1];
                }
                len--;
            }
        }
        cout << str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`cout<<str;` is going to write the string to the output buffer and that is it.  The next time you call it the `str` you write out will start right after that last `str` that was written.  If you want each `str` on its own line then you can use

```
cout << str << endl;
//or
cout <<str << "\n";
```

The reason each line does not retain its newline character is that `getline()` reads until it encounters a newline and then stores everything up to that newline in the string.  It then tosses that newline out instead of adding it to the string.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing like this:

```
cout<<str;
```

You need to output the new-line after your string, which is done as follows:

```
cout<<str<<endl;
```

Comment: Thanks! "My code works for a single white space,but if there are consecutive spaces it will delete only one space, how can I solve this?"